# Express Routes causing infinite loop

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I've created a project using express generator. here is my app.js

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var photo = require('./routes/photo');
var app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/photo',photo);
```

photo.js under routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('viewPictureDetails', { title: 'ID' });
});
router.get('/sample/123', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('viewPictureDetails', { title: 'Sample' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Whenever i try to access localhost:3000/photo/123 it goes into infinite loop. However /sample is working fine.

Comment: What's in `viewPictureDetails` ? Would you be able to share?

Comment: Remove the `next` argument from your `router.get()` handlers.  You should declare them only with `function(req, res)`

Comment: Also, `/:id` and `/sample` conflict.  There is no way to tell which one is supposed to match as they both match on `/sample`.

Comment: How do you know its infinite loop ? Is it showing loading/connecting in browser and not returning anything ? The code you shared should not have such problems.

Comment: @dave viewPictureDetails is just html template

Comment: @jfriend00 next is the optional parameter which is used for middleware. Though as if now i'm not using any middleware. I've tried removing that as well. I've edited /sample/123 (static urls works)

Comment: @MukeshSarma   viewPictureDetails is rendering in loop. I can see that in the terminal logs as well as on the page